# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception occurred only adding admob_flutter in my flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, admob

After adding admob_flutter to my pubspec.yml file I'm not able to build my project. Can anyone know the exact reason of this?.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: {project folder path}\build\admob_flutter\intermediates\res\symbol-table-with-package\debug\package-aware-r.txt

* Try:
Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```